# Invoke model logic in one UserControl from view-model in another UserControl without violating MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Here is WPF application consisting from 3 `UserControl`s:

[image]

`UserControl3` is a part of `UserControl2` content. I keep *MVVM* during developing and using *Prism*.

I need to invoke custom class method (which is *model* in terms of MVVM) in `UserControl3` from *view-model* of `UserControl1`. The restriction that service in `UserControl3` can't be singleton. I suppose to do it one of the following way:

1. Using event aggregator from Prism. `UserControl1` view-model is publisher and `UserControl3` model is subscriber. For this I'll need to create unique Id in `Window` and pass it to `UserControl1` and `UserControl3`.
2. Creating service instance in `Window` and pass it to `UserControl1` and `UserControl3`. Then `UserControl1` just invoke method on this instance.
3. `Window` pass `UserControl2` instance to `UserControl1`. View-model in `UserControl1` will just invoke method of `UserControl2`, which will invoke method of `UserControl3` and so on.

It seems like 2 and 3 approaches violates MVVM. What will you prefer?

Comment: The smaller and the more general is the question the higher is the chance of it being answered here.

Comment: @Den Thanks for your note, I reduced question. I can also remove list, but as well I know, questions without _"what I tried"_ section are not welcomed...

Comment: It's generally hard to get a WPF answer here these days, SO is a better bet, even if it's about design. This question could theoretically be technology-agnostic by the way. I personally cannot see the screenshot, because my employer's IT is paranoid and blocked most of external image hosting. In my last WPF project I relied on ReactiveUI heavily to make state propagation easier. That and viewmodel composition. No mediators/event aggregators.

Comment: `I need to invoke custom class method (which is model in terms of MVVM) in UserControl3 from view-model of UserControl1` -- Why?

Comment: Microsoft seems to endorse using the [Observer Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649643.aspx) in MVC implementations, so I infer that this would extend to this scenario as well.

Comment: @stephen.vakil: That article is pretty old, and it's not MVVM, which is what the OP wants.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I can answer according to particular implementation:  because `UserControl1` contains buttons (and one of them triggers start of processing), while `UserControl3` responsible for actual processing and result output. Why it is not single control and placed such way... well, it have a reason be so, by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question, while focusing mostly on WPF applications applies equally to any GUI application.

When you have two different pieces of the user interface that must interact, you are really left with two possible solutions:

1. **Events**, which you outline as solution #1. The advantage here is the publisher and subscriber are decoupled, and do not have to know the structure of the user interface in order to do their job. The disadvantage here is that subscriber and publisher are decoupled, making UI problems harder to debug.
2. **Composition** (in Object-Oriented terms). You need to encapsulate the logic somehow. If this logic is purely UI logic, then one User Control could have a direct reference to another, if and only if the structure of the UI will now and forever more facilitate this object relationship.

   If the two User Controls cannot know the structure of their containing window, go with option #1 above.

   If the logic is not UI logic, then a service class injected into each User Control upon object creation will work (also known as Dependency Injection).

My preference is to use events or messages between two UI components. An event can be generated by the user, or by the application.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but what I was talking about is how to **not involve** UI to processing data between model and view-model of different controls. This is why I don't want to pass Id through code-behind. But considering my question in terms of any GUI application, I agree that events is better solution, I'll just wait for a while to see if other opinions exist. My particular problem with Id I described in stackoverflow [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39273603/invoke-model-logic-in-one-usercontrol-from-view-model-in-another-usercontrol-wit).

Answer (score 1):

I use MVVMLight, and I would send a notification message which my control would receive and then fire off service record. Same as firing an event in prism.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I checked Greg Burghardt [answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/329937/230076) as more detailed.