# Are signals/events the only way to modify one view from another?

Tags: mvc

I need to set a mode in one view from a different view. Trying to stay organized with MVC. Looking at answer at
[Invoke model logic in one UserControl from view-model in another UserControl without violating MVVM](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/329895/invoke-model-logic-in-one-usercontrol-from-view-model-in-another-usercontrol-wit/329937#329937), *but*

- It seems redundant for a controller to update its view AND fire a signal for anything else to respond to; so, is it better for View1 to emit the signal/event? Or, should model fire it?
- Who owns the signals?
- Signals can be especially dangerous when it comes to collaborative software development (codebase becomes chaos quickly, people get lazy and just fire signals all over the place). What's a solid pattern such cases?

Some code:

```
class View1 {
 ...
 clickModeOption(e){ 
   this.controller.onSelectSomeMode(e.value); //or, should I call View2's controller?
                                              //or, should I emit the signal myself?
 }
 ...
}

class Controller1 {
  ...
  onSelectSomeMode(mode) {

    model.someMode = mode; //i.e. maybe act on model here

    //these two lines look redundant of each other:
    this.view.setSomething();
    somebodysSignals.modeChanged.fire(); //or, model can fire
  }
}

class View2 {
  constructor(signals) {
    ...
    this.signals.modeChanged.add((newMode)=>this.setMode(newMode)); // i'm a cowboy
  }
  ...
  setSomeMode(mode) {...} //my controller isn't calling this :/
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you linked to explicitly discusses WPF and MVVM, but you didn't mention whether or not you're using these.   If you do happen to be using any of the XAML-based UI frameworks (UWP, Xamarin, WPF, etc.), then you should consider looking at the MVVM pattern and investigate supporting libraries such as Prism, Caliburn Micro or MVVM Light which will eliminate a good chunk of boilerplate related to `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

---

> - It seems redundant for a controller to update its view AND fire a signal for anything else to respond to; so, is it better for View1 to emit the signal/event? Or, should model fire it?

Almost certainly the latter.   The 'Model' in any MV* pattern is typically available to be updated from other parts of the application (maybe even from a non-UI element such as a network socket), so really the only sensible place to fire the signal would be within the model, because you certainly do not want something like a network object to have visibility of either your View or your Controller.

That way, in the worst-case scenario (i.e. one where there are no facilities available in the UI framework to reduce the boilerplate) the controller is responsible for updating the View by subscribing to changes in the model, which may be triggered from the View, or a different View, or some external mechanism.

> - Who owns the signals?
> - Signals can be especially dangerous when it comes to collaborative software development (codebase becomes chaos quickly, people get lazy and just fire signals all over the place). What's a solid pattern such cases?

Ideally, the model should own both the state and the signal, encapsulated inside some kind of observable library object to eliminate boilerplate code and prevent the signal being either abused or forgotten.

To elaborate on that somewhat, the *push* capability of the signal should be the sole reserve of the 'setter' method for the state.  The only time that signal should ever be raised is when any part of the application has updated the data - it makes sense to create a very tightly-coupled relationship between the model state and its signal; it's usually undesirable to fall back onto any kind of solution which involves using one without the other.

Conversely, the *pull* capability is fair game; any part of the application might reasonably want to know when the model state has changed, so there's no real benefit in restricting access to potential subscribers.   This is another reason why the signal should be tightly coupled to the state, because anything subscribing to that signal should be allowed to make the assumption that it will receive all state changes, and that a received signal means the state has changed.

---

From a practical point of view, this problem has been solved many times over, albeit in different ways by different UI frameworks, so the best way for you to deal with this depends heavily on the UI framework that you're using.

In the ideal scenario, it'd be a UI framework which supports [Data binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_binding) in which case the amount of Controller boilerplate will be reduced, or maybe even eliminated altogether in some newer frameworks which have been designed with MV* in mind from the outset.

A UI framework which supports data binding will take care of synchronising changes between the View and the Model with little or no code whatsoever in the controller, assuming that a suitable observable/notification mechanism exists in the Model.

If Data binding isn't available in your UI framework, then you can replicate the approach in the Controller yourself, and save yourself the hassle of reinventing the signal mechanism by using something like [Reactive Extensions (Rx)](http://reactivex.io/).

Simple example for a UI framework which doesn't have data binding built-in, using the BehaviourSubject concept in Rx:

```
// Model shared by multiple Views
class MyModel {
    data = new BehaviourSubject<String>("");

    updateData(s: string) {
        this.data.next(s);
    }
}

// Controller for View1 - Repeat as necessary for View2, View3, etc.
class Controller1 {
    constructor(view, model) {
        // Update the view when the data changes
        model.data.subscribe(d => view.setText(d));

        // Update the data when the view changes
        view.textBox1.onTextChange(text => model.updateData(text));
    }
}
```

The Rx `BehaviourSubject` is a stateful observable object which must also be given an initial state - i.e. it combines the model state and the signal, but the push capability for the signal is hidden.

If neither Rx nor any similar equivalent happens to be available for the language you're using, then it should be reasonably simple to replicate a simple variation on BehaviourSubject for yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the amazing answer. Controller subscribing to model answers my problem. I have no framework with data binding (app is React/THREE.js hybrid), so I will organize following BehviourSubject.

Comment: is Redux considered to be a data binding solution? I have been using it, but my impression is that it does the opposite: it facilitates view-model subscriptions, but not deeper model layer observation...

Comment: @user2132190 React isn't really designed for two-way data binding - its creators had a preference for the Flux pattern/Redux.   Flux/Redux is intended to solve your original problem of communicating between multiple components however;  the 'store' allows many components to subscribe to changes - although there's more code/boilerplate involved in creating and dispatching Actions.

Comment: Also, react supports one-way data binding out of the box; so if the component subscribes to state changes, then React is already capable of watching for changes in the state - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38332912/how-do-i-access-store-state-in-react-redux

Comment: Yes but I see React/Redux as providing observer mechanism for view state only; in other words, the local state of a React component and/or the Redux store are no place for my model-layer state...React+-Redux only gives you half of the above infrastructure. . .the views are watching for changes in their state so they can re-rerender; but, the controlling Redux actions/reducers still need to subscribe to model-layer events in order to trigger view changes (in my way of looking at things). Other opinions would be greatly appreciated however :)

Comment: @user2132190 I'm not really sure that I can see your reasoning there.   The Redux store is designed to behave like an 'app state' repository holding the state of the entire app (According to the *[Three Principles](https://redux.js.org/introduction/three-principles)*).   There's a single instance shared across the entire app so any part of the app can dispatch actions to the store, and any part of the app can subscribe to it.    Is there functionality that you feel is missing from the Redux Store, or is it a desire to minimise the use of 'actions'? (avoiding the extra boilerplate/indirection?)

Comment: It is extremely awkward to update store state using pure functions when your app state involves complex objects (i.e. deeply nested)...Redux is not designed to represent such state imo. Also, the store state is directly accessed by the views (at least with React Redux bindings), making it view-model-y. Way I see it: action hits model (via thunk), then reducer takes a skiff off of the payload (some more model object(s)) and places it on the store for any view who wants to subscribe to it, just like a view controller would update its view after acting on some piece of the model.

Comment: "The shoe doesn't fit", so to speak :)

Comment: @user2132190 Indeed, Redux isn't intended to be used with deeply-nested state, although the typical approach is to flatten the data as far as possible by normalising it - essentially following the same kind of structure in the Redux as you might expect from a database - https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape

Comment: But then where to hang the behaviour part of the model entity...

Comment: @user2132190 Wouldn't you prefer to have the core behaviour in their own stateless classes separate from the app state?    Think of Redux like a 'repository' for the state of your app - like a client-side 'data layer'.    Remember that stateless behavioural classes can be simpler to unit test.

Comment: is there a way of taking this conversation offline?

Comment: @user2132190 I think we're moving a long way off topic from the original question, so in keeping with the ethos of StackExchange I think it'd be better start a new question on the topic of the Redux/Flux pattern, (optionally referencing back to this one?), partly in the interest of keeping it out in the open, and most importantly get more visibility/responses from other members here.